# How to parse meta tags from an URL with an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am having trouble with parsing meta tags from an URL with AJAX, I am using Laravel 5.4 and Vue.js 2.3.4 with vue-resource 1.3.4.

I am creating a wishlist project and I want to fill in data from the submitted URL(name, price, brand, etc.). How can I parse the meta tags and populate my fields. I already have tried convert the HTML to JSON data, so I can pick the pricing meta tag out of the JSON object, but this results in an error.

I am using following code:

**app.js**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        url: 'http://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_sony-playstation-4-slim-500-gb-1472861.html',
    },
    methods: {
        setNewValue: function () {
            this.$http.get(this.url).then((data) => {
                console.log(data.json());
                }, (response) => {
                    // error callback
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**show.blade.php**

```
<input v-model="url" v-on:click="setNewValue" name="url" type="url" class="form-control" id="url" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="http://domain.extension/product-1.html">
```

**Error**

This code results in the following error:

```
vue-resource@1.3.4:7 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at vue-resource@1.3.4:7
at <anonymous>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code in the question rather than linking to pastebin.

Comment: @btl I have done that now, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Include the controller method the route is hitting. It seems your response object is incorrect.

Comment: @btl I am calling an external web page, a product page on mediamarkt.nl, I do not have access to their code, ofcourse.

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving a Json response then? What does web inspector show under the network tab? You can't convert HTML directly to json, they are entirely different formats.

Comment: On closer look I'm sure that's your issue, you need to parse the HTML document, not call .json().